# Customise infoWindow google maps AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, google-maps

I have some problems customizing InfoWindow in Google Maps. 
Here is a picture of what I have done so far:

[image]

My problem is I cannot Make the window content wider, I want to shrink the margins on the right.
Also, is there anyway to access the "close" button to customise it?

```
.cadre .title {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0;
border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
width: 100%;
}

.cadre {
margin-bottom: 10px;
left: 0 !important;
right: 0 !important;

}
.cadre .im {
float: left;
height: 100px;
width: 120px;
margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
margin-top: 5px;

}

.cadre .texte {

    text-align: center;

}
```